# Regex to consume between two groups where the second group is optional

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-negation, regex-greedy

I have the following strings:

```
Sally: Hello there #line:34de2f
Bob: How are you today?
```

These strings have three parts to them...

- The "name"; `Sally:` and `Bob:`
- The "text"; `Hello there` and `How are you today?`
- An optional "line identifier"; `#line:34de2f`

I want to grab the "text" between the "name" and the optional "line identifier" using a regex.

This seems like what negative lookaheads are for:

```regex
(?<=:).*?(?!#line:.*)$
```

But this *still* captures the "line identifier".

The following works, but I do not want to actually capture the "line identifier":

```regex
(?<=:).*?(#line:.*)?$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using

```
(?<=:\s).*?(?=\s*#line:.*|$)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HuU98N/3). Details:

- `(?<=:\s)` - a location immediately preceded with `:` and a whitespace
- `.*?` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\s*#line:.*|$)` - a location immediately followed with 0+ whitespaces, `#line:` string or end of string.

You may also use

```
:\s*(.*?)(?:\s*#line:.*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HuU98N/1). Get the contents in Group 1.

**Details**

- `:\s*` - a colon and then 0 or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group #1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?:\s*#line:.*)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `#line:` - a literal `#line:` string
  - `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you! It seems like including the $ in the capturing group was what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (works in Python):

`\w+:\s+?(.+)?\s+?#?.*?`

Examples:

```
import re

tst1 = "Sally: Hello there #line:34de2f"
res1 = re.search(r"\w+:\s+?(.+)?\s+?#?.*?", tst1)
res1.groups(1) # ('Hello there',)

tst2 = "Bob: How are you today?"
res2 = re.search(r"\w+:\s+?(.+)?\s+?#?.*?", tst2)
res2.groups(1) # ('How are you',)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^([^:]*)[:]([^#]*)(?!line.*)
```

[This](https://regex101.com/r/2AKi3t/1) too might work for you:

- `^` - for start of line
- `([^:]*.)` - not a colon repeating in a capture group for the name
- `[:]` - the colon (this could be simplified to just `:`)
- `[^#]` - not a hash symbol (within a capture group and repeating) `([^#]*)`
- `(?!line.*)` - negative lookahead.